# How do you unlock Extreme difficulty missions?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have read about extreme difficulty missions, but how to you unlock them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extreme difficulty missions in Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain are unlocked as part of the main story missions. After the end of Chapter 1 you will get your first extreme missions.

Comment: What is Chapter 1 ? The main story set ?

Comment: Yes, in the intro of the game it states "Chapter 1: Revenge" there are two chapters in the game. At the end of Chapter 1 you will see the Chapter's credits and then get a teaser and the title of Chapter 2, then you will unlock the first Extreme mission. Some speculate more Chapters will be added as DLC